# Incrementing values in django database

Tags: database, django

I want to increment the value in the database without having to perform a hit on the db to find the actual value. Effectively, I would like to do something like this... but this does not work. Any elegant solutions?

```
P.objects.filter(username='John Smith').update(accvalue+=-50)
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out Django's [F() object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model).

You can combine it with `update()` method to update the value based on the previos field value i.e.

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> P.objects.filter(username="John Smith").update(accvalue=F("accvalue") + 50)
```

This will use database's native `UPDATE` method to do what you want to do.

Comment: Better than using regular save method and on top of that thread safe :)

Comment: Can I get incremented value without querying again? This will avoid issues with concurrent accesses

Comment: Can I use same for decrements also?

Comment: @Don, no way. you have to object.refresh_from_db() to obtain the new value. Because the F expression update was done by the database, not django. so, django doesn't know the real value.

Comment: @TianLoon you are right. The OP actually asked how to increment values in DB... then you have to refresh the object to get updated values. Thx!